# What is the difference between ASP.NET 5 platform and MVC 6

Tags: .net, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc, dnx, .net-core

I came across the following statement in the ASP.NNEdocumentation

> ASP.NET 5: The next version of ASP.NET, the open source Microsoft platform for building Modern Web Applications on Windows, Linux and Mac. ASP.NET 5 includes the MVC 6 framework for building web applications. It combines the features of MVC, Web API and Web Pages into a single web framework. ASP.NET 5 also includes SignalR 3 for adding real time functionality to cloud connected applications.
>
> ASP.NET MVC 6: The framework for building web apps on the ASP.NET 5 platform. It features the merged MVC, Web Pages, and Web API from the previous version of ASP.NET.

So what is the difference between the ASP.NET 5 platform and the MVC 6 framework and SignalR?

All the following items have their own version number :

- C#
- .NET (framework, platform)
- ASP.NET platform
- ASP.NET MVC framework
- CLR

How can we figure out what this means?

Comment: Two downvote and one close, no comment. So I ask for explaination about programming and stackoverflow is not the right place, I'll try in the street or coffee shop

Comment: What about [this](http://stephenwalther.com/archive/2015/02/24/top-10-changes-in-asp-net-5-and-mvc-6) for a start?

Comment: @PatrickHofman this is the article that confused me, it seems to me they are mixing both terms without explaining : xUnit is for asp.net mvc , grunt is for asp.net ...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> So what is the difference between the asp.net 5 plateform and the
>   asp.net mvc 6 framework ?

The [ASP.NET Documentation](http://docs.asp.net/en/latest/conceptual-overview/aspnet.html) does a pretty good job of explaning what ASP.NET 5 is:

> ASP.NET 5 is a new open-source an **cross-platform framework** for
>   building modern cloud-based Web applications using .NET. We built it
>   from the ground up to provide an optimized development framework for
>   apps that are either deployed to the cloud or run on-premises. It
>   consists of modular components with minimal overhead, so you retain
>   flexibility while constructing your solutions. You can develop and run
>   your ASP.NET 5 applications cross-platform on **Windows, Mac and Linux.**

ASP.NET 5 is *the framework* which MVC 6 is built on. In the new version of ASP.NET, they've torn apart `System.Web` into separate, detachable components and encapsulated them in NuGet packages. Under the hood, what powers ASP.NET 5 is an execution environment (VM) called [DNX](http://docs.asp.net/en/latest/dnx/index.html) (see [Is .NET Execution Environment (DNX) similar to mono?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30374725/is-net-execution-environment-dnx-similar-to-mono/30374750#30374750) for more on that) which enables it to run on multiple operating systems, not Windows only.

On-top of ASP.NET 5, they've assembled the MVC framework which is version 6. On the side of that they've built SignalR. Think of it as ASP.NET 5 being the (portable) BCL, and MVC 6 being your custom made application which is built on top of that.

Comment: Ok browsing System.Web and System.Web.Mvc helps figuring out what is what. I think it's confusing because there is no widespread alternative to mvc on top of asp.net.

Comment: @remibourgarel You can create one :)

Comment: Don't get me started ;) !

Comment: I used NancyFX in Web API baed project. This was at single way to get analog of MVC at OWIN-based Web API driven app at that time.

Comment: SignalR is not available under asp.net 5. Was delayed to next year.