# How to run a .NET Core dll?

Tags: c#, .net-core

I've build my console application using `dnu build` command on my Mac. The output is `MyApp.dll`.

As it is not `MyApp.exe`, how can I execute it on windows, or even on Mac?

The code is:

```
using System;

class Program
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Hello from Mac");        
    }
}
```

Comment: Aren't libraries unexecuteable because they don't have an entry point put in them?

Comment: @BjarneStroustrup It is a console application. I put the code for sake of clarity.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/30377175/17034

Comment: @HansPassant I got your point, but what about the 'or even on Mac' part? How can I run the built version on Mac. Having the code, I can run it using `dnx run`.

Answer (score 45, accepted):

Add this to your project.json file:

```
 "compilationOptions": {
        "emitEntryPoint": true
 },
```

It will generate the MyApp.exe on Windows (in bin/Debug) or the executable files on other platforms.

**Edit: 30/01/2017**

It is not enough anymore. You now have the possibility between Framework-dependent deployment and Self-contained deployment as described [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/articles/core/deploying/).

Short form:

**Framework-dependent deployment** (.net core is present on the target system)

- Run the dll with the dotnet command line utility `dotnet MyApp.dll`

**Self-contained deployment** (all components including .net core runtime are included in application)

- Remove `"type": "platform"` from project.json
- Add runtimes section to project.json
- Build with target operating system `dotnet build -r win7-x64`
- Run generated `MyApp.exe`

project.json file:

```
{
    "version": "1.0.0-*",
    "buildOptions": {
        "emitEntryPoint": true
    }, 
    "frameworks": {
        "netcoreapp1.0": {
            "dependencies": {
                "Microsoft.NETCore.App": {
                    "version": "1.0.1"
                }
            }
        }
    },
    "imports": "dnxcore50",
    "runtimes": { "win7-x64": {} }
}
```

Comment: new projects don't always seem to have projects.json, in which case you can use the publish options to generate standalone executables depending on the platform, see here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44074121/build-net-core-console-application-to-output-an-exe

Comment: Side note; an exe will only be built if the target OS is Windows.  For other OSes (e.g. Linux) an executable DLL will be generated.  It'll still work; but with a different file extension.  If the DLL is not executable you may need to use `chmod u+x MyApp.dll` to correct the permissions.

Answer (score 7):

You can use `dotnet publish` to generate .exe output for your console app.

More details: [Publish .NET Core apps with the CLI](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-US/dotnet/core/deploying/deploy-with-cli)