# .NET Core 2.1 - dotnet/exe on build, packages are missing

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-core, nuget

I've been developing on one machine and recently tried to install my application on another PC. I think I've deduced to to the nuget packages not being found since in .NET Core, **nuget puts the packages in the local 'Users' folder path.**

I initially added the `<RunTimeIdentifier>` tag to create an exe (which worked on my developer machine). When running the exe on a different machine, the console window will flash very quickly and application stops with no error output (even in Event Viewer).

I also added this tag `<PublishWithAspNetCoreTargetManifest>false</PublishWithAspNetCoreTargetManifest`

in the *.csproj which did not make a difference.

So I tried running `dotnet project.dll` which gave me this error on the other machine.

> An assembly specified in the application dependencies manifest (project.deps.json) was not found:
>
> package: 'Localization.AspNetCore.TagHelpers', version: '0.3.0'
>
> path: 'lib/netstandard1.6.1/Localization.AspNetCore.TagHelpers.dll'

When I 'recreated' the folder structure, lo-and-behold, everything was working.
Is there a way on compile/build that those packages are copied to the bin folder and paths reference those instead? Or am I building/compiling wrong?

Also note that thie project was updated from .NET Core 2.0 to 2.1.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

## Short Answer

It sounds like you want a [self-contained deployment](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/deploying/deploy-with-cli#self-contained-deployment-with-third-party-dependencies). That is what `dotnet publish --self-contained --runtime <some-runtime>` outputs to the `publish` directory.

### Two Examples

Lets say we have an app at `C:\temp\temp.csproj`, and we want to publish it to two [target platforms](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/rid-catalog).

If we publish like this...

```
dotnet publish --self-contained --runtime win-x86
```

... the self-contained executable will be here:

```
C:\dev\temp\bin\Debug\netcoreapp2.1\win-x86\publish\temp.exe
```

If we publish like this...

```
dotnet publish --self-contained --runtime ubuntu-x64
```

... the self-contained executable will be here:

```
C:\dev\temp\bin\Debug\netcoreapp2.1\ubuntu-x64\publish\temp
```

If we then copy the entire `publish` directory to the destination computer, we can execute the `temp` executable, because all of its dependencies are present.

Comment: That was it (publish command)! I just kept doing 'run' and 'build' since when searching the documentation on how to deploy, those were the ones mentioned. I was wondering why I had to manually copy my Views, Thanks!