# Read environment variables in ASP.NET Core

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc, kestrel-http-server

Running my ASP.NET Core application using [DNX](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30374725/is-net-execution-environment-dnx-similar-to-mono), I was able to set environment variables from the command line and then run it like this:

```
set ASPNET_ENV = Production
dnx web
```

Using the same approach in 1.0:

```
set ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT = Production
dotnet run
```

does not work - the application does not seem to be able to read environment variables.

```
Console.WriteLine(Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT"));
```

returns null

What am I missing?

Comment: I've added an environment variable under system and user but when I pull them all I don't see the one I added. Does this only work in production environments?

Answer (score 176, accepted):

Your problem is spaces around `=`.

This will work (attention to space before closing quote):

```
Console.WriteLine(Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT "));
```

The space after `ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT` in this code is not a typo! The problem in the question was having extra space (in SET...), so you must use the same space in GetEnvironmentVariable().

As noted by [Isantipov in a comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37387235/read-environment-variables-in-asp-net-core/37387589#comment82784183_37387589), an even better solution is to remove the spaces entirely from the SET command:

```
set ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT=Production
```

Comment: Dmitry, where should we execute this "SET" command ...  in CommandPrompt??

Comment: Aswartha, It depends on your machine/scenario. You can run this in command prompt before "dotnet run" (in same command prompt) if starting from command prompt, or add to "My Computer" environment variables (for all apps on current machine), or [into `launchSettings`](https://docs.asp.net/en/latest/fundamentals/environments.html) (when staring from VS), or to WebApp configuration when running in Azure.

Comment: Okay, and what happens if we have `=` sign or space ` ` as part of environment variable value? How should we assign/fetch those?

Comment: If you have "strange" chars in value - no problem. Open command prompt, run `set myvar=bla=bla bla` and then `echo %myvar%` - you will see `bla=bla bla`

Comment: You wouldn't want to use 'ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT ' (with a trailing space) - there are features in aspnet core which depend on the value of 'ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT'(no trailing space) - e.g. resolving of appsettings.Development.json vs appsettings.Production.json. (I've added a bit of detail too long to be posted in a comment here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/47884810/1990682 )

Comment: it works on netcore 3.1

Answer (score 29):

This should really be a comment to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37387589/1990682) by [@Dmitry](https://stackoverflow.com/users/460298/dmitry) (but it is too long, hence I post it as a separate answer):

You wouldn't want to use `'ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT '` (with a trailing space) - there are features in ASP.NET Core which depend on the value of `'ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT'`(no trailing space) - e.g. resolving of `appsettings.Development.json` vs `appsettings.Production.json`. (e.g. see [Working with multiple environments documentation article](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/environments)

And also I guess if you'd like to stay purely inside ASP.NET Core paradigm, you'd want to use `IHostingEnvironment.Environment`(see [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.hosting.ihostingenvironment.environmentname?view=aspnetcore-2.0#Microsoft_AspNetCore_Hosting_IHostingEnvironment_EnvironmentName)) property instead of reading from `Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT")` directly (although the former is of course set from the latter). E.g. in Startup.cs

```
public class Startup
{
    //<...>

    // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to configure the HTTP request pipeline.
    public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("HostingEnvironmentName: '{0}'", env.EnvironmentName);
        //<...>
    }

    //<...>
}
```

Comment: can you read `Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable` in `Startup.cs` I'm looking for a particular machine value

Comment: @djack109 I think you should be able to, unless dotnet core blocks it specifically somehow.

Answer (score 7):

If you create the Environment variables at runtime during development then you will get null every time. You have to restart the visual studio because VS read EV at startup only.

Comment: I realized about my mistake only after watching your message. Thank you very much @Umer Waheed