# How to pass parameters to a .NET core project with dockerfile

Tags: docker, dockerfile, docker-for-windows, docker-desktop

I've got a **.NET** Core project (using visual studio and adding the docker files via the [Visual Studio Tools for Docker](https://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/0f5b2caa-ea00-41c8-b8a2-058c7da0b3e4)).

My `DockerFile` looks like this:

```
FROM microsoft/dotnet:1.0.1-core
ARG source=.
WORKDIR /app
COPY $source .
ENTRYPOINT ["dotnet", "MyApp.dll"]
CMD ["arg1", "arg2"]
```

My question is, how do I pass parameters into the project?

```
public static void Main(string[] args)
{
    // how does `args` get populated?
}
```

[image]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I used environment variables which can be set by **docker-compse.yml** too

```
public static class EnvironmentHelper
{
    public const string EnvironmentArguments = "DOTNETCORE_ARGUMENTS";
    private static string[] _arguments;
    public static string[] Arguments
    {
        get
        {
            bool argumentsExist = _arguments != null && _arguments.Any();
            if (!argumentsExist)
            {
                IDictionary environmentVariables = Environment.GetEnvironmentVariables();
                if (!environmentVariables.Contains(EnvironmentArguments))
                {
                    throw new Exception("Environment Arguments do not exist");
                }
                var argumentsHolder = environmentVariables[EnvironmentArguments] as string;
                const char argumentSeparator = ' ';
                _arguments = argumentsHolder?.Split(argumentSeparator);
            }
            return _arguments;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: any chance you can help with how to use this inside the Main and what will need to be added in the Dockerfile TIA?

Answer (score 12):

You can do this with a combination of `ENTRYPOINT` to set the command, and `CMD` to set default options.

Example, for an ASP.NET Core app:

```
ENTRYPOINT ["dotnet", "app.dll"]
CMD ["argument"]
```

If you run the container with no command, it will execute this command when the container starts:

```
dotnet app.dll argument
```

And the `args` array will have one entry, "argument". But you can pass a command o `docker run` to override the `CMD` definition:

```
docker run app arg1 arg2
```

Comment: Hmm that isn't working. I updated the question with a screen shot and an updated DockerFile based on your feedback.

Comment: This worked perfectly fine for me including the parameter override given in `docker run`!

Answer (score 2):

The answer is already given by @Elton Stoneman, but might help someone else, as that approach did not work with a docker environment variable.

I was looking for way to consume argument from `environment variable` instead of pass it to `docker run` command. So here is my approch

```
ENV ARG1=default
ENV ARG2=default
CMD ["sh", "-c", "dotnet /app/StockPods.Core.Listener.dll $ARG1 $ARG2" ]
```

So it will be easy to run this on different platform without worrying to pass anything to docker run command.

To override this behaviour

```
docker run -it --rm -e ARG1=newvalue -e ARG2=newvalue my_docker_image
```

Answer (score 1):

One approach would be to read in environment variables. You would not modify your Dockerfile to do this. Rather, say you run up your container as follows:

```
$ FOO="bar"
$ docker run -e FOO=$FOO devlife/myapp
```

All you now need to figure out is how to read the FOO environment variable in your dotnetcore application. I would try the approach documented here: [ASP .NET Core read environment variables](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37387235/asp-net-core-read-environment-variables)

Answer (score 0):

VS Tools for Docker appear to silently override CMD and ENTRYPOINT arguments. Please see [How to pass command line when debugging docker-compose project in Visual Studio?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52263380/how-to-pass-command-line-when-debugging-docker-compose-project-in-visual-studio) and https://github.com/Microsoft/DockerTools/issues/75