# Dotnet Core docker cmd args

Tags: docker, .net-core

Trying to access the command line args from a dotnet core console application in docker.

This is basically just the default template with default docker compose / dockerfile template.

Tried a few different approaches.

- Add args to ENTRYPOINT in dockerfile
- Added args to CMD in dockerfile
- Added args under build in the docker-compose file

Cant get it to pass it on, how is this usually handled?

Test repo: https://github.com/lasrol/DotnetCoreDockerArgs

Comment: What does your dockerfile look like?

Comment: Forgot to push the docker files to the repo. The docker file is here: https://github.com/lasrol/DotnetCoreDockerArgs/blob/master/TestDocker/Dockerfile

Answer (score 7):

`CMD` is meant as an alternative to `ENTRYPOINT`, or a way to supply arguments to an entrypoint.

Rather than doing:

```
ENTRYPOINT ["dotnet", "TestDocker.dll", $arg1, $arg2]
CMD ["arg1", "arg2"]
```

Which will repeat the arguments,
Try:

```
ENTRYPOINT ["dotnet", "TestDocker.dll", "arg1", "arg2"]
```

or if you want to use both, simply use CMD for all the arguments only.

```
ENTRYPOINT ["dotnet", "TestDocker.dll"]
CMD ["arg1", "arg2"]
```

https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/#cmd

Comment: Tried that also, not working. As statet in the orginal description i have tried the to add them to entrypoint, added as args with CMD and also added to args in the compose file.

Comment: Works for me. See also https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40272341/how-to-pass-parameters-to-a-net-core-project-with-dockerfile/40280368#comment89116050_40280368.