# How to pass command line arguments to a dotnet dll in a Docker image at run time?

Tags: .net, docker

Working on my first Docker image. It is a dotnet program that uses CMD to launch (only one CMD allowed in Docker). I would like to pass the program an argument (an API key) at runtime. After some googling, not finding a clear answer. Entrypoint doesn't seem helpful. Maybe ENV, but it seems ENV is only for Docker. My Dockerfile:

```
FROM microsoft/dotnet
WORKDIR /app
COPY . /app
CMD [ "dotnet",  "/app/netcore/Somename.dll"]
```

Thanks

Comment: I *think* this is a duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48227820 - could you check?

Comment: Yeah, pretty much

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Docker joins `ENTRYPOINT` and `CMD` into single command line, if both use **JSON** notation, like in your example.

This is JSON notation: `CMD [ "dotnet",  "/app/netcore/Somename.dll"]`

This is shell notation: `CMD dotnet /app/netcore/Somename.dll`

Another thing you need to know - what is written in `docker run ... <image_name> ...` **after**  - considered as `CMD`.

So, to conclude.

1. The constant (immutable) part of command line, like `dotnet foo.dll` you can put in `ENTRYPOINT`.
2. Variable part, like additional arguments, you supply with `docker run` and optionally put defaults to `CMD` in `Dockerfile`

Example:

**Dockerfile**

```
...
ENTRYPOINT ["dotnet", "/app/netcore/Somename.dll"]
CMD ["--help"]
```

Command line 1:

```
docker run ... <your image name> --environment=Staging --port=8080
```

Will result in `dotnet /app/netcore/Somename.dll --environment=Staging --port=8080`

Command line 2:

```
docker run ... <your image name>
```

Will result in `dotnet /app/netcore/Somename.dll --help`. `--help` comes from default value, defined in Dockerfile.