# How to pass command line when debugging docker-compose project in Visual Studio?

Tags: visual-studio, docker, docker-compose

I created a .Net core 2.1 console application with Linux docker support using Visual Studio 2017. I can run the application using the following command line

```
docker run myApp arg1 arg2
```

I want to debug it in VS so I set the project `docker-compose` as the startup project and debug run "Docker Compose" in Visual Studio. However, is there a way to set up the command line arguments? (`arg1 arg2` in my example).

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately there is no easy way to do this right now because of the way VS handles debugging into docker containers.

See this issue for more info: https://github.com/Microsoft/DockerTools/issues/75