# Command-line arguments are not passed to the Docker container entrypoint

Tags: visual-studio, docker, docker-compose, dockerfile

I created a console application to run benchmark tests with the [Benchmark.Net library](https://benchmarkdotnet.org/). This application is packed into a Docker container, which is a part of the docker-compose scenario. The `ENTRYPOINT` of that `dockerfile` looks like this:

```
FROM base AS final
WORKDIR /app
COPY --from=publish /app/publish .
ENTRYPOINT ["dotnet", "Benchmarks.dll", "-f", "*"]
```

These args instruct the Benchmark.Net library to run all tests in that assembly.

**The problem**: the arguments are never passed to the console app. The docker-compose doesn't have `command` or `entrypoint` elements, it just references the `dockerfile`. If I use `CMD` in the combination with the `ENTRYPOINT`, it doesn't have any effect:

```
ENTRYPOINT ["dotnet", "Benchmarks.dll"]
CMD [ "-f", "*" ]
```

I need to run it on CI, so the default args should always be passed.

What am I doing wrong? How to make it work?

**UPDATE**: If I run it with the pure `docker run` command, it works just fine and gets the passed arguments. It turns out that when I run it from `docker-compose`, it doesn't print anything. The service definition in `docker-compose.yml` is quite simple, it just references the `Dockerfile`:

```
  benchmarks:
    build:
      context: ../
      dockerfile: test/Benchmarks/Dockerfile
      args:
        - NUGET_SOURCE
    depends_on:
      - another.service
    environment:
      - ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT=Development
    volumes:
      - ${APPDATA}/Microsoft/UserSecrets:/root/.microsoft/usersecrets:ro
      - ${APPDATA}/ASP.NET/Https:/root/.aspnet/https:ro
```

**FINAL UPDATE**: Unfortunately, I forgot to mention in my initial question that I run it from inside the Visual Studio with `dscproj`. Apparently, VS adds its own rules about how to run the docker-compose project, overriding the command line.

There's still no proper solution for it, although there's [an ugly workaround](https://github.com/Microsoft/DockerTools/issues/75).

So, my question is a duplicate of [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52263380/how-to-pass-command-line-when-debugging-docker-compose-project-in-visual-studio). Case closed.

Comment: Are you expecting to receive the single argument `*`, or a list of filenames?

Comment: I expect to receive exactly the args I pass in. For example, if I have `ENTRYPOINT ["dotnet", "Benchmarks.dll", "-f", "*"]`, I think I should get 2 elements in the `args` array: "-f", "*"

Answer (score 1):

I tried to reproduce your issue, but I can't.

Here's my program (I did `dotnet new console` and changed Program.cs to this)

```
using System;

namespace app
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            foreach (var arg in args)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(arg);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

And my Dockerfile

```
FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/sdk:5.0 as publish
WORKDIR /app
COPY . ./
RUN dotnet publish -o out app.csproj

FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/runtime:5.0
WORKDIR /app
COPY --from=publish /app/out .
ENTRYPOINT ["dotnet", "app.dll", "-f", "*"]
```

I then build and run it with

```
docker build -t test .
docker run --rm test
```

and it prints

```
-f
*
```

like you'd expect.

So the arguments are passed to the program. Your issue might be that you don't pass them correctly to Benchmark?

Edit: With this docker-compose.yaml file

```
version: "3.9"
services:
  test:
    image: "test"
    command: ["more", "arguments"]
```

and `docker-compose up` (without -d, so it runs in the foreground), it prints all the arguments - both the ones from the entrypoint and the ones from the `command`.

Comment: This scenario works for me, too. It turns out that when I run it from `docker-compose`, it doesn't print anything. The service definition in docker-compose.yml is quite simple, it just references the `Dockerfile`. I'll update my question with that snippet

Comment: @YanSklyarenko I tried running it with docker-compose and it still prints the arguments. See the bottom of my answer for my minimal docker-compose file.

Comment: I mistakenly didn't mention in my initial post that I run it from inside the Visual Studio using `dvproj`. Apparently, it is VS that's causing the problem - and there's still no fix (although there's an ugly workaround: https://github.com/Microsoft/DockerTools/issues/75). So, turns out my question is just a duplicate of this one: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52263380/how-to-pass-command-line-when-debugging-docker-compose-project-in-visual-studio. I'll update the description and close it as a duplicate, but Thank You for taking time trying to reproduce the issue! :)

Comment: Finding bugs is all about forming a hypothesis and then testing to see if it's true. When your hypethesis turns out to be wrong, you then have to form a new one and in the end you find the bug :)