# How to pass folder path as run parameter in Docker

Tags: c#, docker, containers

This is my Docker file

```
ENV filePath = "C:\newfiles\Prepayment_DB.accdb"
    sourcePath = "C:\srcPath\"
    destPath = "C:\destPath\"
FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/framework/sdk:3.5
COPY bin/ MbrRst/
WORKDIR MbrRst/Release
ENTRYPOINT ["RunApplication.exe", "oradbserv1", "krish", "one", $filePath, $sourcePath, $destPath]
```

When I try to run the above code, it gives me error

> Details: The given assembly name or codebase was invalid. (Exception
> from HRESULT: 0x80131047)

I wanted to pass the folder names and file as input while running the exe. What can I try next?

Comment: Do you want put them into application args?

Comment: That is correct, my application will be taking multiple values as args. I'm able to pass numbers and string, but folder paths I can't and I believe it needs to be mounted and passed, which I don't know how exactly it would be for multiple locations.

Comment: Please check https://stackoverflow.com/a/40280368/14095048

Comment: I think this is one way to pass args to run the image. I'm trying to CREATE the container first and then START by passing args. The args will come from ENV variables, so wanted it that way.