# How to add Gitlab custom variable to ASP.NET Project CI/CD

Tags: c#, asp.net, gitlab, gitlab-ci, app-config

I'm working on ASP.NET project using Gitlab CI/CD and would like to inject the token that are on my *CI/CD Settings>Variables*, to my variable in the controller

controller.cs

```
            var clientId = THE_TOKEN_I_WANT_TO_INJECT1;
            var thumbprint = THE_TOKEN_I_WANT_TO_INJECT1;
            var tenantId = THE_TOKEN_I_WANT_TO_INJECT1;
```

Please advice, how to add Gitlab environment variable in my ASP.NET project

Comment: Have you tried something like [`Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.environment.getenvironmentvariable?view=net-6.0)?

Comment: Tried it, can't retrieve the variable unfortunately.
I have a pipeline that get the variable from Gitlab.
But couldn't find a way to get it inside ASP.NET

Answer (score 1):

Steps to try:

- Set an environment variable in GitLab.
- Call `printenv` in your job scripts. Inspect the output to ensure the variable is set and available to your GitLab runner.
- Add a line to your codebase to read and print the environment variable: https://stackoverflow.com/a/37387589/2675670