# Does .NET Core only have "dll" and not exe?

Tags: .net-core, dll, exe

I just tried the quick start of .NET Core on Windows, following the sample, I created a desktop application. What seems a bit weird is the "main" program is compiled into a "dll" and no longer an "exe" like previous C# code.

Does it mean, from now on, .NET Core compiles everything into an "dll", like java compiles everything into a "class", and no longer need the "exe" because .NET Core VM is the sandbox for all .NET Core apps, like JVM?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/30377175/17034

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, exactly. With dotnet core, Microsoft went a step towards Java/Node/etc style of workflow where you can do most things through a command line tool (dotnet.exe).

I think this makes sense because .NET Core dependencies are app-local, so the runtime isn't scattered everywhere arround the file system as with .NET Framework.

Answer (score 2):

You can create exe also by publishing the project for Windows OS.

For example (.Net Core 2.0):

`dotnet publish -c release -r win7-x64`

You need to specify **win7-x64** in `RuntimeIdentifiers` also in the *.csproj* file