# Executable or dynamic link library?

Tags: c#

Why does a very simple C# winform application generate both an .exe and a .dll?  I'm using Visual Studio 2022, version 17.3.0.

I expected just an .exe.

Comment: A bit out of date, but still relevant: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38391003/does-net-core-only-have-dll-and-not-exe

Comment: Also, newer: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44038847/compile-a-net-core-application-as-an-exe-file-using-visual-studio-2017